# Motherboard lights up but computer doesn’t boot

Tags: motherboard

Recently built a computer and when I tried to boot it for the first time.. nothing. The motherboard lights up and there is an orange light in the bottom right but besides that nothing from the cooling system or the GPU. I pulled it out of the case and tested it with new RAM, no SSD, and no GPU. Same thing. I took it down to barebones including making sure there was no bent pins on the CPU. One thing I noted was that the only was I could turn the PC off when it was in the case was shutting down the power supply, the button would turn it on but not off. It’s my first build so I’m hoping/assuming it was just a stupid mistake I made. Here’s the specs. Let me know if any additional information is needed!

CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3600
Motherboard: ROG STRIX X470-f
GPU: AMD Radeon 5700 XT
Liquid Cooler: Kraken X52
SSD: V-NAND 970 SSD 970 EVO
RAM: Corsair Vengeance Pro 2x8GB
Power Supply: Corsair CX650W [with power on]

.
[image]

Comment: When I had this exact problem turned out the motherboard was definitely defective

Comment: Your photo shows that the external power plug to GPU is not plugged in.

Comment: Sorry you’re right but I had the GPU plugged in several times and still nothing.

Comment: When it's out of the case, how do you turn it on?

Comment: For patkim: as soon as I turn on the power supply it turns on

Comment: You have to momentarily short the Pins meant for PowerOn on the motherboard. See the manual. This is where the Front Panel On switch wire gets plugged in to.

Comment: I was going to short them while testing until I realized just having the power supply on started the motherboard. What good will shorting it do? And this is just for my own clarification. Thanks!

Comment: ATX PSU when switched on from its ON button enters a StandBy mode where it powers the board with 5V standby power. When you press the Front Panel ON switch the PowerON pins on the board get momentarily shorted that releases the PSU from Standby state to full power state and PC starts.

Comment: See this picture https://i.ibb.co/7ywXdvm/mobo.png  From top left 3rd & 4th Pin is for PowerON. That must be momentarily shorted to start the PC.

Comment: That worked! Tysm!

Comment: That’s the way ATX PSU & Motherboards work. When you assemble components back into the case, plug the Power cable & Reset Cable from the cabinet front panel correctly to the respective pins on the board. They do not have polarity. However, Power LED & HDD LED do have polarity. The +ve is indicated by a small triangle on the plug.

Answer (score 0):

Things that it could be also include:

1. That MB might need a BIOS update out of the box. [Here is an example of that issue](https://www.reddit.com/r/AMDHelp/comments/dh8elq/new_ryzen_5_3600_wont_bootpost/) [Another example](https://www.ixsystems.com/community/threads/motherboard-leds-look-ok-but-computer-wont-turn-on.26861/page-2)
2. double check that the [RAM is compatible](https://www.reddit.com/r/AMDHelp/comments/czassw/new_ryzen_5_3600_wont_post/)
3. Check that your power supply is provided the spec'd power
4. one person reported that a bad fan was the problem. I'm not sure if that affects you with water cooling

Nice looking setup BTW